# Where it's better to get a Russian visa - in the USA or Turkey?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, international-travel, russia

I need to get a visa to Russia. Is it easier to get it from USA or travel to Turkey and get it there? Can you fly  to Russia from USA or Turkey and get your visa at the airport in Russia?

Comment: Can be a hassle to get it in Turkey. You better do it in the USA. Also I don't think you can get Visa upon arrival in Russian airport. It depends on your nationality. So I'd recommend you to get in the US. If you want to go to turkey first - then go, but have your Russian visa in advance.